# noindent fail in resume mode

Tags: indentation, resume

I'm writing a resume and want to add a line under each section name:

```
\documentclass[line]{res}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\namefont}{\LARGE \bf}

\name{Tianlun Zhang}
\address{owenzhang1990@gmail.com}
\address{86-15921814184}
\address{ifthiskills.me}


\begin{resume}

\section{OBJECTIVE} 
{\rule[3pt]{\textwidth}{1pt}}} \\
...
\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

But the line has a indentation which I can't suppress with `\noindent`, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to compensate for the length `\sectionwidth`:

```
\documentclass[line]{res}

\renewcommand{\namefont}{\LARGE\bfseries}
\newcommand\Hrule{%
  \par\hspace*{-\sectionwidth}\rule[3pt]{\dimexpr\textwidth+\sectionwidth\relax}{1pt}\par
}

\begin{document}

\name{Tianlun Zhang}
\address{owenzhang1990@gmail.com}
\address{\parbox[t]{3cm}{86-15921814184 \\ ifthiskills.me}}

\begin{resume}
\section{OBJECTIVE}
\Hrule
\section{ANOTHER SECTION}
\Hrule
\end{resume}

\end{document}
```

[image]

According to `res.cls`, `\address` can be used only twice, so the third time you use it overrides the second call; to have more than two lines in the address, you can use a `\parbox` of the proper width as I did in my example.

By the way, `\bf` should be replaced with `\bfseries` in modern LaTeX documents.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why `\bf` has been replaced with `\bfseries`

Comment: @manuzhang One reason is that `\bf` and all the other two letter commands (`\it`, `\sc`) internally use `\normalfont`, so. for example, combinations such as `{\it\bf text}` won't produce italicized boldface but just boldface; the new declarative commands `\bfseries`, `\itshape`, etc. (or their counterparts with arguments `\textbf`, `\textit`, etc.) will produce the desired result in combinations: `{\bfseries\itshape text}`.

Comment: any ideas why only two of the three addresses get displayed?

Comment: @manuzhang according to `res.cls`, `\address` can be used only twice, so the third time you use it overrides the second call; let me think of a possible solution.

Comment: @manuzhang I updated my answer with a solution allowing more than two lines in the address.

Comment: Wow, in that way, I can add more and more... Thanks!

Comment: BTW, I'm new to LaTeX and can't find `dimexpr` in a LaTeX book. Would you please give a link of its manual?

Comment: @manuzhang of course; `\dimexpr` is implemented by e-TeX to evaluate expressions containing lengths; you can find the precise description in the [documentation for e-TeX](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/e-tex/v2/doc/etex_man.pdf) (Section 5).